# RxJava: How to multicast a Completable?

Tags: android, rx-java2

I have a method which returns a `Completable` and I want it to be `multicasted` because any second subscriber should not re-execute the method, instead they should get the same old emitted values. I achieved it using `replay().autoConnect()` as follows and working as expected

```
    public Completable init() {
        return repository.init()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .flatMapCompletable(s -> Completable.fromAction(() -> {
                   // some action
                })).toObservable().replay().autoConnect().ignoreElements();       
        }
```

As you see, the `Completable` I'm converting to `Observable` and after applying `replay().autoConnect()` again back to `Completable` using `ignoreElements()`. It works but, Am I doing it in the proper way?

Is there any shorthand operator that can be used to `Completable` to directly multicast it?

Comment: See http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Completable.html#cache-- .

Comment: Thank you. but can you please explain _**Note that this operator doesn't allow disposing the connection of the upstream source.**_  What does than mean actually?

Comment: Once it has been subscribed, there is no direct way of cancelling the upstream.

Comment: What has to be done if all the subscribers are left and you no more want the source to be active?

Comment: That's what `replay().refCount()` is for along with the conversions you employed.

Comment: but will `replay().refCount()` replays everything when all the subscribers are removed, and a new subscriber comes in at a later point in time?

Comment: No, that will restart the flow.