# RxJava - Multicast completable result

Tags: java, android, rx-java2, rx-android

I have a Completable that makes two network request in sequence (something like a handshake). This operation can be triggered in many places in my code. What I want to achive is:

- When the completable is called multiple times while it's already doing it's work, it should not restart but instead make only one "handshake", then return the "onComplete" event to all subscribers
- When the completable is called for a second time, but it has already compleated its work or faced an error before, it should be restarted (it should not simply cache previous result).

I was trying to apply different solutions, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46670909/rxjava-how-to-multicast-a-completable), but for some reason I can still see multiple requests being made in parallel.

```
public Completable prepareMuticastCompletable() {
  return networkService.makeHandshake() // Completable, makes two network requests
      // transform it into ConnectableObservable
      .toObservable()
      .replay()
      // stay connected as long as there are any subscribers
      .refCount()
      // transform it back to Completable
      .ignoreElements()
      .doOnSubscribe(disposable -> Log.d("Test", "subscribe"));
}
```

If I try to subscribe to this Completable multiple times at once, I'd like to see multiple "onComplete" events but the action performed only once (two HTTP requests).

```
D/Test: subscribe
D/Test: subscribe
D/OkHttp: --> GET https://.../startHandshake
D/OkHttp: --> GET https://.../startHandshake
D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK https://.../startHandshake (503ms, 184-byte body)
D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK https://.../startHandshake (508ms, 184-byte body)
D/OkHttp: --> POST https://.../finishHandshake (151-byte body)
D/OkHttp: --> POST https://.../finishHandshake (151-byte body)
D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK https://.../finishHandshake (151ms, 196-byte body)
D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK https://.../finishHandshake (150ms, 196-byte body)
D/OkHttp: done 2
D/OkHttp: done 1
```

What am I missing? Are there other RxJava methods that I should use instead?

**Edit:**
The subscription (for testing) looks like follows:

```
private Completable prepareCompletable() {
  return prepareMuticastCompletable()
    .andThen(someOtherNotRelevantCompletable()); 
}

//...

prepareCompletable()
  .doOnComplete(() -> Log.d("OkHttp", "done 1"))
  .subscribe();
prepareCompletable()
  .doOnComplete(() -> Log.d("OkHttp", "done 2"))
  .subscribe();
```

Comment: How are you subscribing to the `Completable`? Don't you accidentally recreate the whole sequence on a button click for example?

Comment: @akarnokd I've pasted the subscription snippet

Comment: How is `prepareCompletable()` implemented?

Comment: @akarnokd Hope it's clear now. I was also trying to call the prepareMuticastCompletable() directly (without someOtherNotRelevantCompletable()) but I don't see a difference.

Comment: You *are* recreating the whole sequence by calling `prepareMuticastCompletable` twice.

Comment: Ok, so to make it work I should not only use proper methods, but also keep the reference to the created Completable and reuse it? That would make sense, I'm not sure why I assumed that those methods reuse sameinstance internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to cache the cold sequence and reuse it somehow:

```
Completable c = prepareCompletable()

c.doOnComplete(() -> Log.d("OkHttp", "done 1"))
    .subscribe();

c.doOnComplete(() -> Log.d("OkHttp", "done 2"))
    .subscribe();
```

But note that if the first response is fast, you'd still get double calls.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that if the second subscribtion is called while the first one was already completed I'll get double calls. That's actually what I need and it works! Thank you :)